# Zeros of MacLaurin polynomials for the exponential function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, sequences-and-series

Asked but never answered at MSE.

Let $\exp_n(z)$ denote the nth degree Taylor polynomial of $e^z$ :

$\exp_n(z) = 1 + z + z^2/2! + ... + z^n/n!    \;$ .

The zeros of $\exp_n(z)$ were studied by Szego in the 1920's and 
later by others.   One of the consequences of Szego's results is
that the roots (after division by n) can come arbitrarily 
close to the imaginary axis.

Question: Is it possible for exp$_n$(z) to have a root that lies
precisely on the imaginary axis?

Comment: Can you please give the link to the question at m.se?

Comment: Mathematics Stack Exchange: [Zeros of exponential polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401200)

Answer (score 16):

Indeed the polynomial $\exp_n(z)$ has no purely imaginary zeros.  Write 
$$ 
\exp_n(ix) = C_n(x) + i S_n(x) 
$$ 
in the obvious notation, with $C_n$ for truncations of cosine, and $S_n$ for truncations of sine.   If there is a zero $ix$ for $\exp_n(z)$, then this $x$ must be a common root of $C_n$ and $S_n$, which are both polynomials in ${\Bbb Q}[x]$.  Therefore $C_n$ and $S_n$ must have some non-trivial gcd in ${\Bbb Q}[x]$.  Now we use the beautiful fact (going back to Schur) that $C_n(x)$ is irreducible, which completes our proof.  I learnt of this result of Schur from these [lovely notes of Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf); simply apply Theorem 1 there, or see Corollary 1 which mentions this explicitly.

Comment: I guess one must observe, when $n\ge3$ is odd, that $C_n(x)$ doesn't divide $S_n(x)$.

Answer (score -5):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we know a polynomial of degree $n$ has as many roots in the complex plane.  That doesn't mean have any more information of the roots than that, (e.g. is the Galois group $S_n$?).  There's also the problem that $e^z$ has *no* roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and how to account for that.

Using Stirling formula, Laplace transform, Rouché s theorem and things like that, one can so the roots of such polynomials behave like:
$$ |z \, e^{1-z} | = 1 $$
I don't know where I first learned of these results maybe in American Mathematical Monthly:

- 2003 [On the Zeros of Truncated Exponential Series](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7e2/7f4cd8cc98d83bee6cdf2d66025e81116332.pdf) Peter Walker
- 2006 [Zeros of sections of exponential sums](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0605066) Pavel Bleher, Robert Mallison
- blog [Research in Scientific Computing in Undergraduate Education](https://compmath.wordpress.com/519/)

However, I later found many other sources.  These polynomials appear whenever you have a holomorphic, or entire function or a Laplace transform or otherwise non-zero function and you need to take some kind of approximation.

This result is still counterintuitive, since setting $z = ix$ and observing $e^{i \pi x} \neq 0$ suggests there should never be zeros.

Varga and Carpenter show:

$$ \theta = |\arg z| \geq \cos^{-1} \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) $$

this should be enough to rule out a zero being on the imaginary axis.

---

Using the Cauchy formula, it's possible to write these truncated exponential series as an integral:

$$ (ez)^{-n} p_{n-1}(nz) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\{|s|=1\}}  \frac{s^{-n} \, e^{n(s-1)}}{s-z} \, ds$$

The exponential polynomials are in fact moments of a distribution.

- 2007 [Locating the zeros of partial sums of $\exp(z)$ with Riemann-Hilbert methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1213) T. Kriecherbauer, A.B.J. Kuijlaars, K.D.T-R McLaughlin, P.D. Miller

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: it's more of extended comment

Comment: I may be blind, but I can't see where your answer nor either of the references answers the question of whether or not the polynomials can have imaginary roots

Comment: @Wojowu i don't think you have read the links closely enough.

Comment: You might be right. Perhaps you could point out where in the references the question is answered?

Comment: @Wojowu in the Monthly article of Peter Walker he shows that zeros lie within distance $2e/\sqrt{n}$ of the curve.  Yet, they have zero-free region of distaince $(2e^2)^{-1}(2^{1/n} - 1)$.  That curve intersects the imaginary axis twice.

Comment: A zero-free region around a curve that intersects the imaginary axis twice is not the same as a zero-free region around the imaginary axis. And argument bounded away from zero does not rule out being on the imaginary axis (where the argument is $\pi/2$).

Comment: @GerryMyerson we have ruled out being on (or too close to) the **real** axis.  this is nothing to sneeze at.  Lucia's proof uses number theory arguments to rule out being on $\mathbb{R}$ or $i\mathbb{R}$, but this style of arguments focuses on the infinite places, $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I will try not to sneeze. But OP asked about zeros on the imaginary axis, not about zeros on the real axis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson think of it this way.  The only time this imaginary zero to occur is $z \approx \pm i(n/e)$.  On the imaginary axis, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are bounded, so the truncations are really good approximations to the real thing $$ \left| e^{ix} - \sum (ix)^n / n! \right| < \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n }} $$
Therefore it's hard to have $|e^{ix}| = 1$ but also have $\sum (ix)^n/n! = 0$.

Comment: While the references you provided have interesting results, these are not sufficient to address the problem.  Asymptotics are not enough, because there will be zeros very close to the imaginary axis -- indeed the zeros will be near $\pm in/e$ and on the scale of about $\sqrt n$ near it.  For example, the paper by Bleher and Mallison provides such an asymptotic.  But such results are insufficient to rule out zeros on a particular line, and on the imaginary axis I would expect these Taylor polynomials to get very small, and yet not hit zero.

Comment: @Lucia you are correct they focus so much on convergence to the curve rather than avoiding certain configurations. Yet i don't understand the adverse reaction to my response. Szegö showed the scaled roots are very close to the preimages of the roots of unity of $w = ze^{1-z}$. The distance is $O(\log n/n)$.